# Is it possible to stop drawing shapes with half pixels in InDesign CC?

Tags: adobe-indesign, pixel, cc-2014

Is it possible to stop drawing shapes with half pixels in InDesign CC?

I'm trying to draw shapes that are absolute pixel sizes everytime, but I'm struggling.

I've setup my InDesign document in a Web format. Changed my units and increments to 1px.

I also changed the document grid to pixels and I've set in my view options to Snap to document grid - but still I continue to be able to draw square shapes that have half pixel measurements.

Does any one have any ideas?

[image]

Comment: The 'Snap' in Indesign is not very strong, so it is easy to hit a partial increment when drawing an object. As long as you zoom-in to check that your positioning is on the grid when you first draw the object, you should be able to keep it accurate after that.

Comment: @Rsiel would be nice if they had a 'Snap to pixel' option like photoshop has :/